# UserControl Property Value Checking

Tags: c#, wpf

I am building a custom NumberSelect control (that arrow clicky up'n'down thing). The UserControl has three properties: `Minimum`, `Maximum` and `Value` and I need to get Visual Studio to verify that the three are correct (`Min < Val < Max`) when used in XAML and throw an exception when built from code-behind. I am able to create the exception part but I am not sure about the Visual-Studio-check-values-in-XAML part. Is that even possible?

Thank you for any suggestions!

Comment: As in, a compile time check on the initial values? I don't think that's possible

Comment: As in, I am a user of my future NumberSelect using it in a XAML and write `<cpf:NumberSelect x:Name="mySel" Minimum="20" Maximum="10" Value="15"/>` and VS put squiggly line saying "Really?"

Comment: I don't think you can do that; but I can't say I've tried

Comment: XAML designer will call the UserControl's constructor when loading in designer. Perhaps you can try doing the check in the constructor, not sure if it works that way tho, but there probably wont be a squiggly line, but a banner to indicate exception

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-callbacks-and-validation, read example with min/max/current; And also take a look at different NumericUpDown implementations (for byte, int, double) from `WPF-toolkit`, it might save you some time and efforts.